# How to use CLOS for types rather than instances?

Tags: common-lisp

Imagine some base class `pgj-model` with many methods defined on it, but no slots.  Now consider:

```
(defclass cat (pgj-model) ())

(let ((cat (make-instance 'cat)))
  (ensure-backend cat)
  (insert cat (obj "name" "Joey" "coat" "tabby")))
```

If we want to customize the new class `cat` we can specialize a method like so:

```
(defmethod insert ((model cat) (object hash-table))
  ;; Do something interesting
)
```

This is all very nice.  But neither `pgj-model` nor `cat` have any slots, they are state less.  This is by design as I'm only interested in them as lisp types that methods can be specialized on.  So it seems annoying/confusing to make an instance of class `cat` everywhere you want to call such methods.

One idea is to do:

```
(defparameter *cat* (make-instance 'cat))   ; There can be only one...
...
(insert *cat* (obj "name" "Joey" "coat" "tabby"))
```

Another is to specialize an additional method on all my generic functions like so:

```
(defmethod insert ((model symbol) object)
  (insert (make-instance model) object))

(insert 'cat (obj "name" "Joey" "coat" "tabby"))
```

which seems OK but 1) may confuse users, 2) bloats the generic function with boilerplate and 3) adds some overhead to every method invocation.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach, but which I don't advise because it's not good practice, is to create your own singleton metaclass, so you can specialize `allocate-instance` to `call-next-method` the first time and cache the new instance to return every other time.

```
(defclass singleton-class (standard-class)
  ((instance :initform nil :accessor singleton-class-instance)))

(defmethod allocate-instance ((class singleton-class) &rest initargs)
  (declare (ignore initargs))
  (with-slots (instance) class
    (or instance
        (setf instance (call-next-method)))))

(defclass pgj-model ()
  ()
  (:metaclass singleton-class))

(defclass cat (pgj-model)
  ()
  (:metaclass singleton-class))
```

Note that you need to declare the metaclass for each class, it's not inherited.

You could also specialize `make-instance` in a similar way so it doesn't follow the usual initialization process after the first time.

I didn't deal with synchronization, because your object is stateless, but you might need to address it if you need to reliably keep a single identity.

Finally, this most definitely isn't good practice due to subverting the purpose of `allocate-instance` and thus that of `make-instance` as well.  According to the spec, a Lisp implementation could just compile the following function:

```
(defun test-singleton-class (class)
  (eq (make-instance class)
      (make-instance class)))
```

by optimizing it as if it were defined like this:

```
(defun test-singleton-class (class)
  ;; possibly inlined make-instance calls
  nil)
```

which is not expected with this code.

So, my actual advise is to keep using global variables, or rather global reader functions, e.g. a non-setfable `(cat)`.

Comment: Great stuff.  By *global reader functions* do you mean something like `(let (cat)
         (defun cat ()
           (if cat cat (setf cat (make-instance 'cat)))))`?  Why is that better than a global variable?

Comment: Because you can implement it however you want later on without changing the code that uses it.  If you later decide it's necessary to use a global/dynamic variable (e.g. `*cat*`), such that its value depends on the current thread or that the synch primitives (compare-and-exchange) don't work on local variables, it'll still be accessed with `(cat)`.  If the extra parenthesis bother you, you can `(define-symbol-macro cat (cat))` and just use `cat`.

Comment: I'd leave the function anyway.  Depending on your implementation, I'd declare the function inline or define a compiler macro for it, if you're not expecting to redefine the function at runtime (e.g. by loading patches).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `eql` specializers to dispatch on symbol identity rather than class:

```
(defgeneric insert (thing container))

(defmethod insert ((thing (eql 'cat)) (container hash-table))
  ...)
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain why you think this is superior to say the `defparameter` suggestion above?

Comment: @gtod: you do not need a globally special variable, you just need something that has an identity.  A symbol does that.  When seeing the method definition or an invocation of it, you just can see "ah, a `cat`", instead of "what was that `*cat*` thing again?".

Comment: But using this `eql` system if I now want a `'black-cat` do I not have to go and change the definition of all my existing methods so that they treat black cats the same as cats?  In other words, how do you get the same effect as `(defclass black-cat (cat))` and then specializing `insert` on the new class while not specializing `fetch`, `update` etc?

Comment: You don't.  There's no further possible specialization for `eql` specializers than the compared object.  If you want that, stick with singletons or global variables.